# Installing Apache on Windows for manual use and multiple users

Tags: apache

I installed Apache HTTP Server on our Windows system, to work on a home project; it's for use by "localhost" only.  When I installed it, the two options were to install it as a service, for all users, using port 80; or to install it for just the current user, run manually, using port 8080.  I selected the second.  However, while I'd prefer for it to use port 8080 and be run manually, I'd like it to be set up so that my wife can run it as her user.  (Allowing all users would be OK.)  I don't see an httpd.conf entry for this.  Is there a way to do this either through httpd.conf or a command-line option?  I'm guessing I could do this in the registry but I don't want to mess with it if I don't have to.  (P.S. There's no need to have multiple instances run simultaneously.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can do from within **httpd.conf**; any settings in there affects the server itself and not how it is accessed by a program
Well, you have a few options: 
 
1. Uninstall the software and re-install it choosing the **all users** option. That would be your best choice. 
2. Found the location of the folder where it was installed (or where **apache.exe** is located as that is the needed file to run) and see if you can create a shortcut link into it from within your wife's account. Apache server doesn't care who runs it as long as that file can be executed. The problem you might face is Windows OS preventing you from running it, especially if it requires administrative rights. 
3. Install a software such as WAMPServer for her. Of course, that means two similar software on the same machine. 
 
If I have to do it, I would go the first route. Every other option is gonna be a little complicated to work with. 
 
Hope the explanation is clear and the answer helps.

Comment: (1) I don't remember an "all users" option except one that also ran it as a service on port 80.  I know I can change the port number in httpd.conf, but I was hoping not to run it as a service.  I might have to give up on that, though.  But that's something I can try.  (2) I've already created a shortcut link.  The program runs, but doesn't write anything to the logs and doesn't serve the files correctly, and I haven't been able to get any diagnostic info to tell me why.  I've already tried to make sure the files and folders are accessible.  But definitely thanks, I'll probably do #1.